# Peek&Pop for UITableViewCell in a master-detail app

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a sample app from RayWenderlich: [UISearchController Tutorial: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) - please get the [**finished** version](https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2017/10/CandySearch_4_Finished.zip)

In this project we have a list of candies in a Table View and if we tap on a row we are getting a details view for that candy. For the details view to work we are setting the `DetailViewController`'s `detailCandy` propery with the selected candy.

I wanted to add peek and pop functionality just for fun. I tried the easy way: just enabled the *Preview & Commit Segues* in the storyboard and waited for it to work out of the box. It indeed calls the `prepare(for:sender:)` method with the appropriate segue but unfortunately I can't seem to determine the `selectedCandy` from the `tableView` itself.

1. The `tableView`'s `indexPathForSelectedRow` is `nil`.
2. I *can* solve this problem using private API (quick fix) by getting this property: `tableView.value(forKey: "pendingSelectionIndexPath") as! IndexPath`
3. I know that I can implement peek&pop manually from code with the help of the `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate` and my problem goes away.

Does someone have any idea how to solve this problem easily and **elegantly**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)` in `prepare(for:sender:)` does the job.

This is what my `prepare(for:sender:)` looks like:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

    var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    if indexPath == nil {
        indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)
    }

  if let indexPath = indexPath {
    let candy: Candy
    if isFiltering() {
      candy = filteredCandies[indexPath.row]
    } else {
      candy = candies[indexPath.row]
    }
    let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
    controller.detailCandy = candy
    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
    controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
  }
 }
}
```

It checks if the cell was selected or if the user was peeking and adjusts accordingly.

Comment: Happy to help :)